# dotenv won't load in docker container

Tags: python, docker

I'm trying to run a python app in a docker container. The python app takes it's secrets from a `.env` file and uses `dotenv.load_dotenv` in python to pull the secrets in. Works absolutely fine when I run locally.. so I assumed it HAD to be to do with the version of Python running on the base image, however.. I've tried it with the exact same version as I'm running locally and it's still failing.

Docker file:

```
FROM python:latest
WORKDIR /casp
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /casp
ENTRYPOINT [ "python3" ]
CMD [ "main.py" ]
```

In my python app:

```
from pathlib import Path
from dotenv import load_dotenv

env_path = Path('.') / '.env'
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=env_path)
```

I actually tried abandoning this idea completely, and reverting to passing the environment variables in using `docker run -e` but, it turns out `Flask` relies on `dot_env` also, and as such it fails there also.

I've done a fair amount of looking already and it seems a lot of people do have Docker / Dotenv issues, but none seem to directly match this.

Previous posts suggest it could be related to the location, but the path here is literally just `./env` which matches the container, since the `WORKDIR` is created then the entire app directory is copied into it, which includes `.env` and `main.py`.

Error I'm seeing is:

`ImportError: cannot import name 'load_dotenv' from 'dotenv' (/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dotenv/__init__.py)`

Current test is using `Python 3.9`. Locally I'm running `Python 3.85` - I have tried changing the `Dockerfile` to match this version... same error.

**EDIT:**

```
(venv) root@jon-Blade:/home/jon/PycharmProjects/caspv2# pip freeze | grep dotenv
python-dotenv==0.14.0
(venv) root@jon-Blade:/home/jon/PycharmProjects/caspv2# grep dotenv requirements.txt 
python-dotenv==0.14.0
```

**EDIT EDIT:**

```
root@jon-Blade:~# docker exec 2ce1ff67d74f pip list | grep dotenv
python-dotenv  0.14.0
```

**EDIT EDIT EDIT:**

From within the *container*:

```
>>> import dotenv
>>> dir(dotenv)
['__author__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__email__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '__version__', '_get_line_', 'ast', 'get', 'load', 'os', 'save']
```

From within the venv in my *terminal*:

```
>>> import dotenv
>>> dir(dotenv)
['IS_TYPE_CHECKING', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'compat', 'dotenv_values', 'find_dotenv', 'get_cli_string', 'get_key', 'load_dotenv', 'load_ipython_extension', 'main', 'parser', 'set_key', 'unset_key']
```

As we can see, in the container it's `load` and in the terminal it's `load_dotenv`. More importantly, it's different! Using the exact same version in `requirements.txt`

**Terminal:**

```
(venv) jon@jon-Blade:~/PycharmProjects/caspv2$ pip freeze | grep dotenv
python-dotenv==0.14.0
```

**Container:**

```
root@2476f65ffa10:/casp# pip freeze | grep dotenv
python-dotenv==0.14.0
```

Version from **Terminal**:

```
(venv) jon@jon-Blade:~/PycharmProjects/caspv2$ python --version
Python 3.8.5
```

Version from **Container**:

```
root@3aa5c393846e:~# python --version
Python 3.8.5
```

Running `pip show python-dotenv` on both also confirms the exact same details, line for line!

This is certainly a fun one, it's confusing... but there has to be something funny going on.

**EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT :)**

In the container I upgraded `python-dotenv` to `0.15.0`:

```
root@8a94c1e22b8a:~# pip show python-dotenv | grep -i version
Version: 0.15.0
```

However:

```
>>> import dotenv
>>> dir(dotenv)
['__author__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__email__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '__version__', '_get_line_', 'ast', 'get', 'load', 'os', 'save']
```

It's still giving me the wrong package.

Comment: Updated my Answer hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

Is dotenv in your requirement.txt with a version? I would have left a comment under the question but I’m unable to need more rep

```
python-dotenv==0.15.0
```

Update:
Looking at your dir(dotenv) you should see it's not giving you the right package so firstly update your python-dotenv to 0.15.0 in your requirement.txt like I've shown above.
Then update

```
FROM python:3.8.5
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/opt/venv
RUN python3 -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV
ENV PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"

# Install dependencies:
WORKDIR /casp
COPY requirements.txt /casp/
RUN pip install -r /casp/requirements.txt

# Run the application:
COPY . /casp /casp
CMD ["python3", "main.py"]
```

The Main problem is your container isn't accessing python-dotenv even though you are installing it. If this doesn't work either docker destroy and rebuild your container. I've done this locally and I have a working docker container.
If it speeds up your development you could add your ENV variables this way.

ENV ADMIN="jack"

You can access it using

```
import os
admin_name = os.environ['ADMIN']
```

Comment: Yes, I populated requirements.txt with pip freeze > requirements.txt from a working venv. 

I see it install also when the image is built.

Comment: Your error is suggesting that the load_dotenv isn’t in your dotenv library you are installing share your requirement’s.txt in the question please. Also run `docker exec <container ID> pip list` In the cmd line

Comment: You wan’t to check with the ‘docker exec {container ID} pip list’ you don’t have dotenv and python-dotenv @jonnybinthemix

Comment: I've added the requirements info into the question. The container won't, so I'll remove the entrypoint and then check pip list without the program running, since it causes the container to fail to start.

Comment: I've added the output of docker exec {container ID} pip list to the bottom of the question.

Comment: Added some more tinkering notes to my original question.

Comment: Have you tried upping the version to 0.15.0 i know it’s silly but I’ve had a few things like that in the past @jonnybinthemix

Comment: Added some notes.. I can't think what else could be causing this, so I've raised an issue on github for it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not sure how much of an answer this is.. but I've just got it working.

If I install `python-dotenv` by using the `upgrade` switch, it shows the correct results from `dir(dotenv)`

My workaround for this was to remove `python-dotenv` from `requirements.txt` and then add another line in my `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install -U python-dotenv
```

It now works and the app runs.